# Getting a Zerocoin for d bitcoins

Tags: zerocoin

I've read the [Zerocoin](http://spar.isi.jhu.edu/~mgreen/ZerocoinOakland.pdf) paper by Miers et al. and understood most of the concepts.

- How do I get a zerocoin for some denomination in bitcoin? e.g. If I spend (d bitcoins + txn fee) in a bitcoin txn and get a (c, skc) pair, then is this mint txn accepted into the blockchain just like a normal bitcoin txn?
- What does it mean when they say the currency is placed in escrow?

Thank you.